# Call function in external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

In JSFile.js:

```
alert('hello');

$('#mydiv').change(function(){
   alert("i'm here");
})
```

In a script in html file:

```
<asset:javascript src="JSFile.js"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mydiv').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

The JS file gets imported correctly cause i see the 'hello' alert when i load the html file, but the 'i'm here' alert never pops up. If i copy the code from the js file and paste it below the document ready, the alert pops up.

Does anybody know how to make it work the way I want? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are binding event *before* element is available in DOM, resulting in `$('#mydiv')` returning empty matched set

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://jsbin.com/xokado/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: @Quentin Binding event is done from external file, i guess included from head

Comment: @A.Wolff — Probably, but the OP should create a test case to demonstrate the problem and not leave us guessing how to fill in the gaps in the supplied code.

Comment: @Quentin Oh ya, sorry, i get your point!

Comment: The Javascript file is included in head, yes.

Comment: In that case, [this question applies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) (but I've already voted so can't mark as dupe)

Comment: Well, the element i'm targeting it's actually in a partial view that is rendered inside the html file where the document ready is. Maybe that's the reason @JamesThorpe. Thanks for the link to the other question.

Answer (score -3):

I cant recreate but have you tried:

```
$('#mydiv').change(function(){
   alert("i'm here");
}).change();
```

Define the change event, and trigger it immediately. This ensures the event handler is defined before calling it.